# How do I inherit from a base class and add another property?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class that's used to construct a request object to pass to an API:

```
public class BaseRequest
{
    public string messageId { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public string updatedAtMin { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }

    public BaseRequest(DateTime updatedAtMin, int page)
    {
        this.messageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
        this.updatedAtMin = updatedAtMin.ToString("o");
        this.page = page;
    }
}
```

However, there is an edge case where an optional parameter needs to be added to the request object.  My first thought was to inherit from the BaseRequest class but I can't see how to create this and make it syntactically correct.

```
public class CaseRequest : BaseRequest
{
    public bool extraParameter { get; set; }

    public CaseRequest(bool extraParameter) : base()
    {
        this.extraParameter = extraParameter;
    }
}
```

Error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'updatedAtMin' of 'BaseRequest.BaseRequest(DateTime, int)

Can anyone please help?  Esssentially, I want to create an instance of the BaseRequest with the usual constructor but adding in the extraParameter.

Many thanks, and apologies for my woeful ignorance!

Comment: The base class doesnt have parameterless constructor, yet you are calling it with `base()`

Comment: As a side-note, I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions for your properties.

Comment: @JonSkeet - many years ago I was a stickler for naming conventions (remember Hungarian notation?)  However, I was persuaded that they don't really matter, particularly with IntelliSense.  Can you give me an idea of why you "strongly advise" me to start following them?  (As an aside I've just started work on this legacy project and I'm following the naming pattern I've found, just as I'm having to put up with not having braces for simple if statements)

Comment: Because it makes it clearer for everyone reading them, who is used to the conventions. The C# conventions are almost universally followed in my experience. Even if the project you happen to be working on violates them, you're presenting sample code here for people to read who *aren't* working on that project - so it's best to optimize for their reading experience, which is to follow the normal conventions.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet - if I post code again I'll be sure to do as you suggest.

Answer (score 6):

Your base class' constructor has parameters:

```
public BaseRequest(DateTime updatedAtMin, int page)
```

But you're not passing any values for those parameters:

```
base()
```

Ideally you would expand your constructor to accept those parameters and pass them along:

```
public CaseRequest(DateTime updatedAtMin, int page, bool extraParameter) : base(updatedAtMin, page)
{
    this.extraParameter = extraParameter;
}
```

You could also pass default values if you don't want the user to set them.  Or create a parameterless constructor in the base class.  Etc.  As long as you pass something to satisfy a base constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is simple as the error indicates.

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'updatedAtMin' of 'BaseRequest.BaseRequest(DateTime, int)

You define a constructor in BaseRequest. This eliminates the default parameterless constructor. Which means...

> public CaseRequest(bool extraParameter) : base()

does not find base() because base () does not exist.

YOu MUST accept the other parameter and pass them into the defined base to be syntatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following

```
public class BaseRequest
{
    public string messageId { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public string updatedAtMin { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }

    public BaseRequest(DateTime updatedAtMin, int page)
    {
        this.messageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
        this.updatedAtMin = updatedAtMin.ToString("o");
        this.page = page;
    }

    public BaseRequest() {
    }
}

public class CaseRequest : BaseRequest
{
    public bool extraParameter { get; set; }

    public CaseRequest(bool extraParameter) : base()
    {
        this.extraParameter = extraParameter;
    }
}
```